# position expression

Tags: after-effects-expressions

Im trying to do an expression to my object. I want to make him come out from the side to center. I searched a lot but I didnt find any expression. I can do it with keyframes but I need expression only. 
Please, can someone help me with expression?

Answer (score 1):

Expressions work by returning a value to the property to which they are applied. So if you apply an expression to the position property and you put in the expression

```
[1,2]
```

in the expression editor, it will return the value [1,2] so that will be the position of that layer, i.e x= 1 y=2. Because the values 1 and 2 don't change, it will stay there forever.

If you have an expression on the position where the x value increases over time then the layer will move right. So for example if you put the expression

```
[time, thisComp.height / 2]
```

the layer will start at [0, 540] (if the comp is 1080 px high) and move right at the rate of 1 pixel per second. For a HD frame it will reach the right side at around 1:17:20. That might be too slow, but you can use maths to adjust it. For example to make it twenty times as fast you could multiply it by 2, like so:

```
[time * 20, thisComp.height / 2]
```

So in the expressions editor you can see the drop-down with the available objects, properties and methods. You can use these along with the pick-whip to build up the expression to do whatever you need.

You might want to start looking at [Dan Ebbert's](http://motionscript.com/) site. I can't quite believe that anyone could spend any time researching expressions and *not* find this site in the search results.